How can I access localhost from multiple devices on the Wi-Fi network?
I recently learned about the JavaScript Geolocation API, and I want to view the output on my mobile phone while coding on my PC using VS Code and Live Server.
here is my code
const display = document.getElementById("display");

        function getLocation() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
            } else {
                display.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not available in your browser!";
            }
        }
    
        function showPosition(position) {
            display.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + "<br/> Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
        }
    
        function showError(error) {
            switch (error.code) {
                case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                    display.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation.";
                    break;
                case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                    display.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable.";
                    break;
                case error.TIMEOUT:
                    display.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out.";
                    break;
                case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                    display.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred.";
                    break;
            }
        }

How can I correctly access localhost from multiple devices on the same Wi-Fi network?
Are there any additional configurations or settings I need to adjust to make this work?
I attempted to access the localhost URL from my PC's browser and then copied and pasted it into my mobile phone's browser. However, this didn't work.

You first have to open a port on your PC, so that other devices in the same WIFI can access your website on a specific port. Here are the steps how to do it on Windows and here for Linux. You don't have to do any port forwarding, if you want to access your website in the same LAN.

Thanks for your answer but I found the alternative way and now its work. I opened a port on my PC to allow other devices on the same Wi-Fi network to access my website. Then, I adjusted my firewall settings to ensure that inbound connections were allowed. It was important to mark my Wi-Fi connection as private to enable access from other devices on the same network. After completing these steps, I was able to access my website from other devices by using my PC's IP address and the port number. For example, with my PC's IP address set to 192.168.1.100 and port 8080
